# How to ask for user input in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'd like my script to ask for the selection of 2 points before doing some calculation and display.
These points would have to be clicked on the current graph, not specified in script's parameters.
Built-in "fixed range" indicator does it but I cannot find how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting data from mouse clicks is not currently possible.

But what exactly are you trying to do?
There could still be a way to get the information you want.

Comment: I am trying to select lowest and highest points on a specific area of the graph not the currently framed one. If it's not possible then I'll try to think it differently. Thanks for the information

Comment: ok, so for something like that, you can do it by getting two dates from user input via the settings.
then in your code, if the time is between those dates, calculate the highest and lowest as you go.

though depending on what you want to do with them, you may not be able to run your logic until AFTER the latter date has passed.